# The value in certain column in the first table is equal to the column value in the another table want to display the datarow in that particular table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to link when these two tables which app_lect column in appointment table's Chai is the same as the value Chai in the lecturer table.

Then I want to display out the appointment time, date, student name which is same row with the app_lect (value Chai).

This first table is about the appointment form data insert into the database

```
        CREATE TABLE `appointment` (
      `stud_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `stud_num` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `app_course` enum('A','B','C','D','E') NOT NULL,
      `app_lect` enum('Chai','Lim','Diana','Siti','Joseph') NOT NULL,
      `app_date` date NOT NULL,
      `app_time` time(6) NOT NULL,
      `app_reason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `app_approve` enum('pending','approve','reject') NOT NULL,
      `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

This is the data insert into appointment table.

```
        INSERT INTO `appointment` (`stud_name`, `stud_num`, `app_course`, `app_lect`, `app_date`, `app_time`, `app_reason`, `app_approve`, `app_id`) VALUES
    ('Chong Jun Xuan', 'A1111', 'A', 'Chai', '2021-04-15', '12:50:00.000000', 'Discussion', 'pending', 19);
```

Table structure for table `lecturer`

```
     CREATE TABLE `lecturer` (
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `staff_ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `lect_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `lect_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `lect_password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `lect_phonenum` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `lect_course` enum('A','B','C','D','E') NOT NULL,
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Data insert into lecturer table

```
        INSERT INTO `lecturer` (`user_id`, `staff_ID`, `lect_name`, `lect_email`, `lect_password`, `lect_course`) VALUES
    (1, 'A1001', 'Chai', 'chai@gmail.com', 'chai', 'A'),
    (2, 'A1002', 'Lim', 'lim@gmail.com', 'lim', 'B'),
    (3, 'A1003', 'Diana', 'diana@gmail.com', 'diana', 'B'),
    (4, 'A1004', 'Siti', 'siti@gmail.com', 'siti', 'C'),
    (5, 'A1005', 'Josept', 'joseph@gmail.com', 'josept', 'D');
```

alter table

```
        ALTER TABLE `appointment`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`);
        ALTER TABLE `lecturer`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);
        ALTER TABLE `appointment`
      MODIFY `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=26;
        ALTER TABLE `lecturer`
      MODIFY `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
```

Coding for displaying the details from the appointment table.

```
            <?php 
            $sql= "SELECT * FROM appointment,lecturer WHERE appointment.app_lect= lecturer.lect_name order by app_id";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die( mysqli_error($con));
    
            
             echo    "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Appointment ID</th>
            <th>Student name</th>
                <th>Student Number</th>
                <th>Appointment date</th>
                <th>Appointment time</th>
                <th>Appointment reason</th>
            </tr>";
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
               echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['app_id']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['stud_name']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['stud_num']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['app_date']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['app_time']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['app_reason']."</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
           }
                 echo "</table>";     
                 
            ?>
```

I would like to know the following:

- SQL query code for displaying the data from the appointment table
- link this two tables as when appointment.app_lect=lecturer.lect_name so display the data in row with the condition

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. The above is clearly MySQL, *not* SQL Server. Thank you,

Comment: [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) will allow columns that hold a cross-reference to another table to be the joint in queries.